# Responsive images in inline SVG

Tags: html, image, svg, media-queries, responsive

I have tried to find an example or answer to this but haven't been able to do so.

The way we optimize images so that unnecessary large images doesn't have to be loaded when they don't need to, can be done like in the example below:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8888/example.jpg" alt="sample 1" srcset="http://localhost:8888/example-1024x1024.jpg 1000w, http://localhost:8888/example-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost:8888/example-150x150.jpg 150w, http://localhost:8888/example-768x768.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px">
```

So my question is if this could also be done the same way or in some other way with images used in inline SVG for optimization.

Image used in SVG like in this example:

```
<svg role="img" width="100%" height="100%">
  <title>Ocean wave</title>
  <desc>Ocean wave in crystal clear blue water.</desc>
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
      ...
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image href="img/image.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"></image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `<foreignObject>` instead of `<image>` seems to do the trick as this enables you to use any kind of HTML element inside the SVG.

```
<svg role="img" width="100%" height="100%">
  <title>Ocean wave</title>
  <desc>Ocean wave in crystal clear blue water.</desc>
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
      ...
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
    <img src="img/image.jpg" alt="sample 1" srcset="http://localhost:8888/example-1024x1024.jpg 1000w, http://localhost:8888/example-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost:8888/example-150x150.jpg 150w, http://localhost:8888/example-768x768.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px">
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```